# Realm Notification Causes Exception: Object has been deleted or invalidated

Tags: realm

*Swift 4, Realm 3.5*

I have a Realm notification set up on an `NSOutlineView` that works well for insertions and modifications, but **deletions** always cause this exception:

```
2018-05-23 11:57:09.890455-0700 MyApp[57060:9443837] [General] Object has been deleted or invalidated.
2018-05-23 11:57:09.893594-0700 MyApp[57060:9443837] [General] (
  0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff27eeb32b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
  1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff4f565c76 objc_exception_throw + 48
  2   Realm                               0x000000010074696f ___ZN12_GLOBAL__N_115makeBoxedGetterIN5realm10StringDataEEEP11objc_objectm_block_invoke + 289
  3   Foundation                          0x00007fff29f7404c -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKey:] + 284
  4   Realm                               0x00000001007618b1 -[RLMObjectBase valueForKey:] + 85
  5   Realm                               0x0000000100762b77 -[RLMObjectBase hash] + 145
  6   Foundation                          0x00007fff29f4a3eb probeGC + 80
  7   Foundation                          0x00007fff29f4d994 -[NSConcreteMapTable removeObjectForKey:] + 56
  8   AppKit                              0x00007fff255d262f _NSOVFreeRowEntry + 59
  9   AppKit                              0x00007fff25abc83a __70-[NSOutlineView _removeItemsAtIndexes:inParentRowEntry:withAnimation:]_block_invoke + 253
  ...
```

Here is what my notification observer looks like:

```
let realm = try! Realm()
let results = realm.objects(Workspace.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "order", ascending: true)

tokenWorkspace?.invalidate()
tokenWorkspace = results.observe { [weak self] (changes: RealmCollectionChange) in
  switch changes {
  case .initial:
    //The listener is ready
    self?.refreshData(reload: true)
  case .update(_, let deletions, let insertions, let modifications):
    self?.refreshData(reload: false)

    self?.workspaceOutlineView.beginUpdates()

    self?.workspaceOutlineView.insertItems(at: IndexSet(insertions), inParent: nil, withAnimation: .slideDown)
    //--- (!) The crash seems to be on the next line...
    self?.workspaceOutlineView.removeItems(at: IndexSet(deletions), inParent: nil, withAnimation: .slideUp)
    self?.workspaceOutlineView.reloadData(forRowIndexes: IndexSet(modifications), columnIndexes: IndexSet([0]))

    self?.workspaceOutlineView.endUpdates()

  case .error(let error): print("\(error)")
  }
}
```

Prior to attempting the `removeItems` call, I am refreshing my datasource array, `workspaces`, in `refreshData()` like this:

```
func refreshData(reload: Bool){
  let realm = try! Realm()
  let workspaceObjects = realm.objects(Workspace.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "order", ascending: true)

  workspaces.removeAll()
  workspaces.append(contentsOf: workspaceObjects)

  if reload{
    workspaceOutlineView.reloadData()
  }
}
```

I can't figure out where the deleted object is being accessed and causing the exception. It seems the `NSOutlineView` still has a reference to it somewhere.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

Your `removeItems(...)` call in the observe closure is too late. The object is already invalidated, but you hit the outline view with the `removeItems(...)` call with a node still referencing the invalidated object.

I'd suggest to remove the item from the outline view outside the closure, maybe in the action method that handles the user's delete request.

Secondly, you should have a look at the index you give to `removeItems(...)`:

What you get from realm in the .update enum is an index relative to the realm objects. The outline view method however expects an index relative to its parent. So what may be the 10th item in your "flat" realm result, might be the second item relative to its parent node in the outline view.

Check `outlineView.childIndex(forItem: ...)` the get the relative child index.